# How to import resnet in local

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I have installed keras and when I'm trying to import resnet by command

```
# from resnet.py
import resnet
```

I'm getting the below error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization' (C:\Users\Toshiba\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\normalization\__init__.py)
```

After importing resnet I have to build model using resnet18

Comment: Keras doesn't have a ResNet18 model. You can see the list of ResNet models available [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/#available-models). Can you provide more details about how you have installed Keras/Tensorflow? The standard way to import a model would be something like `from tensorflow.keras.applications.ResNet50 import ResNet50`

Comment: I have used pip install keras to install keras and the assignment I'm doing asked me to import resnet from resnet.py and for resnet.py they have given below code I'm not sure how to import resnet from resnet.py

Comment: The problem is that the code in your resnet.py is outdated, as BatchNormalization should be imported from keras.layers, not from keras.layers.normalization

Comment: Can you please share the link f updated resnet.py code and how to import that code in local machine